# Why Java doesn't allow object on stack?

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am taking some classes and object lessons in Java having C++ background. I want to know the reason why we cannot choose the objects to be declared on the stack memory? Why must everything go on the heap except for the primitive types?

Here's something to clarify what I was asking.

Essentially, if we have:

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Then why cannot we have it on stack in the first place?

Comment: What do you think is everything? Please update the question with your answer.

Comment: Reverse the question: what is the advantage you see in allowing objects to reside on the stack in a memory-managed language?

Comment: I think the following should help :)
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/65289

Comment: Java has a cpp background?

Comment: @RomanC: Except primitives like 
I have said.

Comment: @Tdorno: Lol I mean I have C++ background.

Comment: @user963241 I didn't get you.

Comment: Anyways, I'm reading a book known as "Core Java Volume I" which claims that all Java objects live on the heap in chapter 4.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Timely, and *predictable*, deallocation of resources.

Answer (score 5):

One of the strongest attractors of the original Java design (in mid-1990s) was *simplicity*. Supporting heap-based objects is essential, whereas stack-based ones are an optimization. Java is not alone here: many languages take that approach (LISP, Haskell, JavaScript, Ruby, etc.). Stack-based allocation does happen in Java, but only as an internal optimization trick and not something that the user can control.

Especially keep in mind that there is an essential difference in how a pointer to an object passed to a function ("a reference passed to a method" in Java-speak) can be treated by the callee: it is not allowed to retain the pointer if it's stack-based. This alone creates huge complications and bug opportunities.

Finally, stack-based objects bring much less to a garbage-collected language than to manually-managed languages like C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

The data on the stack, say a C struct, disappears after the function call has returned. Hence one would need copying and correction of pointers.
Think of the hidden extra functionality needed here:

```
struct S* f() {
     struct S s = ...;
     g(&s);
     return &s;
}
```

Java was meant as simplification, having its own management of memory, and doing things immediately on the heap seemed more direct, less convoluted.

This in view of C++, with its copy constructors, pointers and aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow explicit on stack allocation of objects.  The language is not competing with low level languages such as C, and the creators of the language made this choice as a simplification.

However times change, and Java has grown since its humble beginnings.  As the JVM becomes more sophisticated, automatic allocation of objects to the stack has become possible.  The rationale for this is similar to the 'register' keyword in C;  let the compiler manage the low level detail.  It has become better at doing it than humans.   In Java automatic allocation of objects onto the stack has been hampered by two factors, firstly the Sun/Oracle JVM is very old and very complex now.  It is difficult to change, and Oracle has been careful about preventing backwards breaks.  Secondly, so far their work on stack allocations has not yielded the large benefits that were expected.  It did improve some situations, but the JVM has its own trade offs and behaviours.   So this comes down to a question of time/pay-off and priorities.  I believe that work to improve the benefits of automatic allocation continues behind the scenes;  but there are no plans to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple, the key advantage of objects on stack is that the memory is automatically managed for you. When function puts objects on stack, they are cleaned from memory on function exit.

Since java already has automated garbage collection, this key advantage doesn't bring that much.

Sure there is a speed of access performance price that you might pay by being unable to allocate objects on stack directly, but as Marko mentioned, there are internal optimizations that might do just that.

Answer (score -1):

> Why must everything go on the heap except for the primitive types?

This statement is not accurate. Primitive types can go on the heap as well if they are part of a class instance. A local variable is stored on the stack, where as class variables are on the heap.

As for why objects are stored on the heap. It's after all a design decision. One reason is that it is a managed area in the JVM that is subject to garbage collection. As a managed area in the JVM, it may be organized in generations and may grow or shrink in size. See [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) from the JVM specification:

> The Java Virtual Machine has a heap that is shared among all Java Virtual Machine threads. The heap is the run-time data area from which memory for all class instances and arrays is allocated.
>
> The heap is created on virtual machine start-up. Heap storage for objects is reclaimed by an automatic storage management system (known as a *garbage collector*); objects are never explicitly deallocated.